# Can I control surveillance system remotely without an app/browser?

Tags: surveillance

I'm looking to purchase a POE surveillance system that allows me to store the DVR away from the TV, yet still be able to control the system with an external infrared sensor or the App and still watch on my TV.

I don't want to have to view through a browser, but actually be able to view it on a normal TV through the HDMI (or whatever input) and still be able to select the different cameras and navigate on the TV.

Is this particular feature called something or is there a way to do this with some/most surveillance systems?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a security camera that has HDMI and implements HDMI-CEC then you may be able to control it through your television.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple methods that I can think of here, both come with their own pro's and cons.

**Method 1: Build Your Own System**

This isn't too hard of a task to accomplish on your own if you have experience with some software development and have a desktop computer with (or even an old laptop) with an HDMI port and a good amount of storage space. You would need to get a few IP cameras which you can use to store video over FTP on the designated computer, and you could use software such as VLC to view the camera outputs ([here's a link to an example](http://www.guidingtech.com/9554/vlc-stream-media-live-camera-feed-how-to/)). Simply connect the computer to your TV via HDMI and you're set. Should you feel ambition you could write a small app of your favorite flavor (Java, C++, Python? etc).

**Pros:**

- This is can be insanely cheap compared to most commercial systems (whether it be a flat or monthly fee), especially with a Raspberry Pi 0 W and Camera (about $40 per pi+camera).
- This allows for the flexibility and customization that you want, because you built it and can modify as needed.
- Companies don't have access to or store video on your cameras, and won't be stored "in the cloud."
- Its a fun project and a great learning experience.

**Cons:**

- Your written code is not audited for security measures, nor would you probably make many system updates once the system is working. This would leave you vulnerable compared to buying a commercial system that will make all the necessary updates for you.
- You have to put in some time, you can't buy some parts and expect setup to take an hour.

**Method 2: Buy a Commercial System or Service**

This option would require you to do some google searching, note taking, book marking, and maybe some phone calls to find a system that meets your needs and your budget. Personally, I hate monthly fees and seeing all my money fly out the door every month for an indefinite period of time. While this may save you time in, building a system, you will also spend a good amount of time finding the right product or service.

**Pros:**

- You will most likely have an enterprise team dedicated to providing updates to your system that will take the pressure off of you as far as security goes.
- Little setup time required (compared to previous option).
- Customer support system to call with any issues or concerns you may have.
- Downtime would be minimal or non-existent.

**Cons:**

- You may end up paying a monthly fee or hundreds of dollars.
- Your video will be stored on a computer you don't own.
- You may have to compromise on particular features that you want.
- You will need to spend a bit of time researching various products and services to find the best fit for you.

To answer your main question, it would certainly be feasible to avoid app or browser if you built your own system, but purchasing one may require compromise. The way I see it, these are your two options. This community isn't meant to do your googling for you, and ultimately it comes down to doing the research to find what suits you best. To get you started, some popular companies for consumer security include Netgear Arlo, Samsung, Piper, ADT, Doyle, TimeWarner, and more. There are plenty of options available on amazon as well. I have not personally used any of these companies so I can not provide any feedback related to their services. I wish you the best of luck in your search!